# How to plot a list of points on Overpass turbo (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using overpass turbo web http://overpass-turbo.eu/#

after typing in

```
[out:csv(::lat,::lon;false)];
relation(2081626);>;out;
```

I get already a list of coordinates, under "data" tab

```
48.0786156  11.5510212
48.0769149  11.5502003
48.0763526  11.5505930
48.0768127  11.5502292
48.0761811  11.5499233
```

...

How could I plot this list of coordinates on "Map" tab as a route, on the map

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Overpass? You can view the relation here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2081626

Comment: I don't believe that is possible in the Overpass UI. Overpass is a data retrieval engine, not a generic mapping tool. You can see a specific relation on the main OSM site though: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2081626

Comment: why don't you just omit the `csv` output mode? e.g. `[out:json];relation(2081626);out geom;`

Comment: @BradHards Overpass is also a decent visualisation tool and doing this seems to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[out:csv(::lat,::lon;false)];` and use just `relation(2081626);>;out;`
?

Results in http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/uoe